# Access Cloud Based SharePoint with Python

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am attempting to write a script that will allow other scripts to read and edit files stored on the company's SharePoint as if they were stored locally.  To do this, I sought out the help of our local SharePoint admin. However, he claims that this simply cannot be done on cloud based SharePoint.  **Is this true, and if so, why?**

If it matters, below is the script I am attempting to use, it receives a HTTP 403 error:

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, user, password)

site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)

for sp_list in site.lists:
    print sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title']
```